# How do I compile the ncurses form_driver_w test example?

Tags: ncurses

A directory teeming with demonstration files called `ncurses-examples-20200725` is available here:

[ftp://ftp.invisible-island.net/ncurses-examples/current/ncurses-examples.tar.gz][1]

I wanted to study the workings of the `form_driver_w` example so I built the programs in accordance with the README file.

If I run `./form_driver_w`, the result is a command line statement: "This program requires the wide-ncurses and forms library".

That outcome occurs because the following statement is not true:

`#if USE_WIDEC_SUPPORT && USE_LIBFORM && (defined(NCURSES_VERSION_PATCH) && NCURSES_VERSION_PATCH >= 20131207)`

Trying to trace how and where in the labyrinth of header files and compiler switches `USE_WIDEC_SUPPORT` is set to true is diabolically difficult. Furthermore, since the source code uses `form_driver_w`, I would have expected the compiler to link to ncursesw. However the compiler call is like this:

`gcc -g -O2  -o form_driver_w ../ncurses-examples-20200725/form_driver_w.o ../ncurses-examples-20200725/popup_msg.o -L/lib64 -I. -I. -I../test -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DDATA_DIR=\"/usr/local/share\" -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_XPG5 -g -O2  -DNCURSES_STATIC -lform -lmenu -lpanel -lncurses   -lutil  -lm`

My Debian Bullseye installation includes a binary called `form_driver_w` in the `/usr/lib/ncurses/examples/` directory. That binary runs correctly. I do not know how it was compiled.

Compiling and running `form_driver_w` must be a trivial task. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to configure using ncursesw:

```
configure --with-screen=ncursesw
```

(and, of course, have the development library available).

The place to find this information is by running

```
configure --help
```

which lists a few options:

```
General Options:
  --disable-stripping     do not strip (debug info) installed executables
  --enable-string-hacks   work around bogus compiler/loader warnings
  --with-pkg-config{=path} enable/disable use of pkg-config
  --disable-echo          do not display "compiling" commands
Curses Version-dependent Options:
  --with-ncurses-wrap-prefix naming-prefix for ncurses wrapped-variables
  --disable-widec         disable checks for wide-character functions
  --with-curses-dir=DIR   directory in which (n)curses is installed
  --with-screen=XXX       use specified curses-libraries
  --with-ncursesw         use wide ncurses-libraries
  --with-ncurses          use ncurses-libraries
  --with-pdcurses         compile/link with pdcurses X11 library
  --with-curses-colr      compile/link with HPUX 10.x color-curses
  --with-curses-5lib      compile/link with SunOS 5lib curses
  --with-Xaw3d            link with Xaw 3d library
  --with-Xaw3dxft         link with Xaw 3d xft library
  --with-neXtaw           link with neXT Athena library
  --with-XawPlus          link with Athena-Plus library
  --with-x                use the X Window System
  --with-x11-rgb=FILE   file containing X11 rgb information (EPREFIX/lib/X11/rgb.txt)
  --with-form-libname=XXX override form basename of library
  --with-menu-libname=XXX override menu basename of library
  --with-panel-libname=XXX override panel basename of library
  --disable-panel         disable checks for panel functions
  --disable-menu          disable checks for menu functions
  --disable-form          disable checks for form functions
Testing/development Options:
  --enable-warnings       test: turn on gcc compiler warnings
  --with-dmalloc          test: use Gray Watson's dmalloc library
  --with-dbmalloc         test: use Conor Cahill's dbmalloc library
  --with-valgrind         test: use valgrind
  --disable-leaks         test: free permanent memory, analyze leaks
  --disable-rpath-hack    don't add rpath options for additional libraries
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Running `./configure --with-screen=ncursesw` and afterwards `make`, attempts to compile all of the test programs. I found that 16 of them raised a compiler error: `undefined reference to _nc_strdup`. If anybody is interested, my workaround was to doggedly identify each of the 16 programs and then delete them from the list in the `programs` file. After that, I deleted `ncurses_cfg.h` and all of the object files. Then I ran `./configure --with-screen=ncursesw` and `make`. Voila, `./form_driver_w` appears to be running correctly.

Comment: I see (the configure script should have checked for `strdup`) - perhaps recent breakage.